# How to create route for many controllers and actions in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, router

I have DB table defined with four columns: short, controller, action, id
And using this columns I want to create routes dynamically. For example:
http://mywebsite.com/short should point to the page represented normally by address http://mywebsite.com/controller/action/id

Is it possible to make something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple google search reveals [this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/iworm/2010/01/10/how-to-implement-dynamic-route-in-cakephp).

In `routes.php`, you can init a model object `$routeModel = ClassRegistry::init('Route')`, query `$routeModel->find('all')` and loop over the results calling `Router::connect` for each row.

Comment: Thanks. "dynamically" is the word, I've not used when googling. :)